# Permutation Groups - Rewrite as disjoint cycles / transpositions

Tags: finite-groups, permutations

Why is this true? "(1243)(3521): Written as a product of disjoint cycles, we get (354)."

Shouldn't (1243)(3521) = (354)(21)? Where did the (21) go?

Thanks!!

Comment: Compose from  right to left  and see the effect of composition on1 and 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cycle $(3521)$ sends $3$ to $5$, and the cycle $(1243)$ does nothing to $5$, so the product sets $3$ to $5$. The cycle $(3521)$ sends $5$ to $2$, which $(1243)$ sends to $4$, so the product sends $5$ to $4$. The cycle $(3521)$ leaves $4$ alone, and $(1243)$ sends it to $3$, so the product sends $4$ to $3$. This establishes that the product has a cycle $(354)$.

Now what about $1$ and $2$? The cycle $(3521)$ sends $1$ to $3$, and $(1243)$ sends $3$ right back to $1$, so the product leaves $1$ fixed. The cycle $(3521)$ sends $2$ to $1$, and $(1243)$ sends $1$ right back to $2$, so the product leaves $2$ fixed. Thus, the product is $(1)(2)(354)=(354)$, since we don’t normally write out the $1$-cycles (fixed points) explicitly.

Comment: This is a fine answer, and I'm glad you actually posted as an answer; It can dull (and drown out) the noise from others.

Comment: @brian Thanks Brian! :) For the fixed 1 and 2, is there a theorem that you used? I am mapping out my own lemma that if the element sends back to itself by going through all the cycles, then that element is fixed?

Comment: @user1799252: You’re welcome! There’s really nothing to be proved there: applying the permutations in turn from right to left defines their product, so if that sends an element to itself, it is by definition a fixed point of the product.